# Delete based on a group in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to delete records with the same combination of records from a table using this query. The syntax works in PostgreSQL but not in SQL Server. What could be the reason?

```
    DELETE FROM  Table_stg
         WHERE (cid , t_date , i_location , item ) in
             (SELECT b.cid , b.t_date, b.i_location, b.itemFROM  Table_vw b)
```

Comment: You're missing a whitespace before the `from` in the inner query, not sure if that's the real issue or just a problem pasting here. Anyway, what error are you getting?

Comment: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.
This is the error I'm getting

Comment: A `SELECT` within an `IN(...)` can only return one column in SQL Server. You would need to use separate `IN()`s for that statement to work.

Comment: you may have an unwanted comma from previous query.

Answer (score 5):

In SQL Server (or any other database) you can use `exists`:

```
DELETE FROM Table_stg a
     WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM Table_vw b
                   WHERE a.cid = b.cid AND a.t_date = b.t_date AND
                         a.i_location = b.location AND a.item = b.item
                  );
```

SQL Server doesn't allow tuples for `IN`.

Comment: thanks a lot , I didn't know the records were not allowed for IN